# Realizar busqueda en DataGridView mediante textbox c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Hola quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar a realizar una busqueda, en un **DataGridView** que desde un **TextBox** al escribir, es decir en el eventeo **KeyPress** se vaya refrescando la tabla para poder ver el registro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven en la imagen en textbox donde dice Buscar: al ingresar por ejemplo el nombre **oso** que en el Datagridview solo me muestre ese dato de los tres.

**Nota: No uso una base de datos, los datos los guardo en un fichero txt y estoy usando el IDE visual studio 2012 lenguaje C++**

De ante mano muchas gracias, resumiendo quiero que me haga una busqueda por nombre.

Comment: Ya has hecho 6 preguntas en SO. A estas alturas deberías saber que para que te demos una respuesta buena es necesario que publiques parte del código. Es facil que des por supuesto cosas que no van a ser obvias para quien te intenta ayudar y eso puede invalidar cualquier respuesta que te demos

Answer (score 1):

Lo que deberías hacer en el evento KeyPress es iterar las filas del DataGridView, buscando el valor correspondiente, y entonces realizar la acción que necesites.

en c++ no sabría como iterarlas, en C# es algo como

```
foreach(DataGridRow row in dgv1.Rows)
{
  if(row[1].value == stringabuscar)
  {
    row.SetSelected();
  }
}
```

Imagino que sería algo similar pero con un for hasta el Length de dgv1.Rows.

Todo ésto suponiendo que el nombre de tu DataGridView es dgv1

Disculpar errores de sintaxis, hace mucho que no programo en .Net